# After setState the DOM not reRender in Paginations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i created a simple pagingation in react and using JSONPlaceHolder fake API. the given data shown in material UI components. for the pagination, i use material UI component.

but there is a problem, which is when i change the page number, i have to click twice on it to appear the data in the table.

i use useState and setState will execute and we have to see rerender, but it doesn't. all codes is in App.jsx.

even i cant use next and previous button in pagination component.

````
function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [slicedUsers, setSlicedUsers] = useState([]);

  const countPerPage = 5;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const [firstIndex, setFirstIndex] = useState(0);
  const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = useState(countPerPage);

  const [allPageCount, setAllPageCount] = useState(0);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((users) => {
        setUsers(users);
        setSlicedUsers(users.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex));
        setAllPageCount(Math.floor(users.length / countPerPage));
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const paginationController = (e, value) => {
    setCurrentPage(value);
    
    setLastIndex(currentPage * countPerPage);
    setFirstIndex(lastIndex - countPerPage);
    
    setSlicedUsers(users.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          gap: "10px",
          height: "100svh",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        {isLoading ? (
          <>
            <CircularProgress color="warning" />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <TableContainer
              component={Paper}
              sx={{ boxShadow: "0 0 12px #15544b" }}
            >
              <Table>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Body</TableCell>
                </TableHead>

                <TableBody>
                  {slicedUsers &&
                    slicedUsers.map((user) => (
                      <TableRow key={user.id}>
                        <TableCell>{user.id}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{user.title}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{user.body}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>

            <Pagination
              count={allPageCount}
              color="primary"
              hideNextButton
              hidePrevButton
              onChange={paginationController}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the excellent answer of Mike K:
you can also utilize `useEffect` to make changes in `currentPage` and re-slice the `users` array whenever the page changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const newFirstIndex = (currentPage - 1) * countPerPage;
  const newLastIndex = currentPage * countPerPage;

  setSlicedUsers(users.slice(newFirstIndex, newLastIndex));
}, [currentPage, users, countPerPage]);
```

by adding **another** `useEffect` hook, the `currentPage` state change triggers the effect, and handles slicing the data accordingly.

doing this we have to remove the direct calls to `setSlicedUsers` from both `paginationController` and the `fetch` effect to avoid duplicates.

the whole code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  CircularProgress,
  TableContainer,
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableCell,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  Pagination
} from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [slicedUsers, setSlicedUsers] = useState([]);
  const countPerPage = 5;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [allPageCount, setAllPageCount] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setUsers(data);
        setAllPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / countPerPage));
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newFirstIndex = (currentPage - 1) * countPerPage;
    const newLastIndex = currentPage * countPerPage;
    setSlicedUsers(users.slice(newFirstIndex, newLastIndex));
  }, [currentPage, users, countPerPage]);

  const paginationController = (e, value) => {
    setCurrentPage(value);
  };

  return (
    <Container
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        gap: "10px",
        height: "100svh",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      {isLoading ? (
        <CircularProgress color="warning" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <TableContainer
            component={Paper}
            sx={{ boxShadow: "0 0 12px #15544b" }}
          >
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Body</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {slicedUsers.map((user) => (
                  <TableRow key={user.id}>
                    <TableCell>{user.id}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.title}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.body}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
          <Pagination
            count={allPageCount}
            color="primary"
            onChange={paginationController}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `firstIndex` and `lastIndex` are not initialized with `React.useState`, therefore the component doesn't rerender. You can't do:

```js
lastIndex = currentPage * countPerPage;
firstIndex = lastIndex - countPerPage;
```

Your usage of `currentPage` is correct, so do the same. Change the syntax to the following:

```js
const [firstIndex, setFirstIndex] = React.useState(0);
const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = React.useState(0);
. . .
setFirstIndex(. . .);
setLastIndex(. . .);
```

Full working code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const countPerPage = 5;
export default () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [slicedUsers, setSlicedUsers] = React.useState([]);

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(1);

  const [firstIndex, setFirstIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = React.useState(countPerPage);

  const [allPageCount, setAllPageCount] = React.useState(0);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((users) => {
        setUsers(users);
        setLastIndex(currentPage * countPerPage);
        setFirstIndex(lastIndex - countPerPage);
        setSlicedUsers(users.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex));
        setAllPageCount(Math.floor(users.length / countPerPage));
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const paginationController = (e, value) => {
    setCurrentPage(value);
    setLastIndex(currentPage * countPerPage);
    setFirstIndex(currentPage * countPerPage - countPerPage);
    setSlicedUsers(users.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>users:{users.length}</div>
      <div>slicedUsers:{slicedUsers.length}</div>
      <div>currentPage:{currentPage}</div>
      <div>lastIndex:{lastIndex}</div>
      <div>firstIndex:{firstIndex}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setFirstIndex((prev) => prev + 1)}>
        paginate...
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: 77830531-6whnrl]

Comment: it doesn't work. that is happened when i click page two. watch this image please,  https://postimg.cc/YGXKcKPJ

Comment: Update your question with the updated code

Comment: the updated code replace the old one

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if it works for you. If it doesn't specify the expected results and the actual results.

Comment: unfortunately still it requires two click on page numbers to reRender DOM.